# Can't use the contrib in Idris

Tags: idris

I'm trying to use some of the contrib code in Idris (0.12.3), specifically `DivMod` (https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Data/Nat/DivMod.idr)

But nothing that I do seems to work. I can't load it in my file with 
`import  Data.Nat.DivMod`
it returns an error `Can't find import Data/Nat/DivMod`

I tried to start idris with the flag `-p contrib` but it doesn't change anything  and `idris --listlibs` shows correctly :

```
base
contrib
effects
prelude
pruviloj
```

Does anyone know how I can load this module in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Idris file typechecks with `idris -p contrib`:

```
module SO39700630

import Data.Nat.DivMod

x : 10 `DivMod` 4
x = divMod 10 3
```

The output using 0.12.3 is:

```
$ stack exec idris -- -p contrib SO39700630
     ____    __     _
    /  _/___/ /____(_)____
    / // __  / ___/ / ___/     Version 0.12.3
  _/ // /_/ / /  / (__  )      http://www.idris-lang.org/
 /___/\__,_/_/  /_/____/       Type :? for help

Idris is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type :warranty.
Type checking .\SO39700630.idr
*SO39700630> x
MkDivMod 2 2 (LTESucc (LTESucc (LTESucc LTEZero))) : DivMod 10 4
```

Comment: I deleted my file, copy/pasted your's and it worked. Then I rewrote my code and... it worked. Maybe I put some blank character somewhere that prevented the compilation. However, now it works. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Atom, you should create an .ipkg file. Check here:
http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/packages.html